# Symfony2, autoloading translations from other bundles

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, autoload

I want to translate some messages in Twig template, but I think, the best way is to divide them into separate files.
So i want to push some translations of UserBundle messages into Resources/translations/messages.pl_PL.xliff of that bundle.
But in other bundle, i want to make something like `{% trans from "UserBundle" %}Username{% endtrans %}`, but it doesn't work. I read about loading files into translator, but is there way to autoload them?

Answer (score 1):

```
    {{ 'Username' |trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

---

You can set a default domain as well:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    <p>{{ 'Username'|trans() }}</p>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

***Note:*** Don't forget to clear the cache:

`php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: I don't want to translate variable called Username, I want to translate string.

Comment: Here is a real example in the FOSUserBundle: [View](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Profile/show_content.html.twig#L4-5) and [Translation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml#L27-L28)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you HAVE to clear the cache. `php app/console cache:clear`. This is very likely to be the reason.

Comment: I did it, but still doesn't work.
Maybe should I register somewhere translation file?